# Zend Framework with Wordpress in subdirectory

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, zend-framework2

I want to serve wordpress from public_html/blog. I have already install zend framework and i would like to know how to achieve this. My .htaccess file looks like

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^\.htaccess$ - [F]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain\.example\.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.domain\.example\.com$
RewriteRule ^/?$ "http\:\/\/simple\.com\/" [R=302,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^other\-domain\.example\.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.other\-domain\.example\.com$
RewriteRule ^/?$ "http\:\/\/simple\.com\/" [R=302,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} =""
RewriteRule ^.*$ public/index.php [NC,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/public/.*$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /public/$1

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]

RewriteRule ^public/.*$ public/index.php [NC,L]
```

I am totaly green in htaccess files and this is my first case with it. Is that structure already correct?

Comment: you don't need to do anything fancy. Just use the standrd htaccess from FZ2 in your root, and then the standard htaccess from WP in the blog folder and it will work just fine as the WP htaccess will override the ZF2 htaccess

Comment: My problem is every request is going to index.php which is located in public folder. That configuration only serves static files from public directory.

Comment: So when i write simple.com/blog its redirect me to simple.com/public/blog

Answer (score 0):

In your ZF htaccess, allow apache to service existing files and directories:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]
```

Now apache will see that /blog is a real folder and then load the htaccess inside there (your WP htaccess) when the user goes to /blog.

You should be able to have your two htaccess rules separate without the need for complex routing

Comment: Problem is that my index.php file and all content are in public directory. And in my htaccess file I have that rule which rewrite all urls with public prefix